# How to use LAG function in oracle pl sql until non zero or last row is reached?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window-functions

I want to write LAG function for table column in such a way that if column value is zero it should lag value for that id if it is again zero for previous row it should LAG again until it reaches a non zero row or last row please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show sample, data expected output, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LAG() IGNORE NULLS ...`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652) combined with a `CASE` statement:

```
LAG(
  CASE COLUMN_NAME
    WHEN 0
    THEN NULL
    ELSE COLUMN_NAME
    END
) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY OTHER_COLUMN )
```

**For example**:

```
WITH DATA ( id, value ) AS (
  SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 0 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT  id,
        value,
        LAG(
          CASE VALUE
               WHEN 0
               THEN NULL
               ELSE VALUE
               END
        ) IGNORE NULLS
          OVER ( ORDER BY id )
          AS prev_non_zero_value
FROM    DATA;
```

**Outputs**:

```
        ID      VALUE PREV_NON_ZERO_VALUE
---------- ---------- -------------------
         1          1                     
         2          0                   1 
         3          0                   1 
         4          2                   1 
         5          0                   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to call the same table twice, (for example, call them A and B).

In B, filter out all the rows where the value equals zero, and then do a simple LAG(field,1).

Then just JOIN the two tables.

Voila!