# In sql, how do I obtain the prior value conditional on another value?

Tags: sql, window-functions, lag

Thank you in advance.

I need to calculate the yellow column in the screenshot.

Basically, look for the prior qualified customer. If they were missed, then the yellow column should have a 1.

[image: Screenshot to show what I need]

Here is the query that builds the data in the screenshot

```
with data as (
select 'a' customer, 'Jan 1' Period, 0 qualified, 0 missed, 0 desired_behavior_prior_qualified_was_missed
UNION 
select 'b' customer, 'Jan 2' Period, 1 qualified, 1 missed, 0 desired_behavior_prior_qualified_was_missed
UNION 
select 'c' customer, 'Jan 3' Period, 0 qualified, 0 missed, 1 desired_behavior_prior_qualified_was_missed
UNION 
select 'd' customer, 'Jan 4' Period, 1 qualified, 0 missed, 1 desired_behavior_prior_qualified_was_missed
)

select * from data
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? ie. sql-server, mysql, etc.

Comment: Examine the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35529315/2055998

Comment: I am using Snowflake

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528383/how-to-use-lag-function-in-oracle-pl-sql-until-non-zero-or-last-row-is-reached/35529315#35529315) I got the answer

```
with data as (
select 'a' customer, 'Jan 1' Period, 0 qualified, 0 missed, 0 desired_behavior_prior_qualified_was_missed
UNION 
select 'b' customer, 'Jan 2' Period, 1 qualified, 1 missed, 0 desired_behavior_prior_qualified_was_missed
UNION 
select 'c' customer, 'Jan 3' Period, 0 qualified, 0 missed, 1 desired_behavior_prior_qualified_was_missed
UNION 
select 'd' customer, 'Jan 4' Period, 1 qualified, 0 missed, 1 desired_behavior_prior_qualified_was_missed
)

, data_1 as (
select *, 
LAG(
  CASE 
    WHEN qualified = 0
    THEN NULL
    ELSE concat(customer,period)
    END
) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY period ) period_qualified_customer

from data
order by period)


select  a.customer,
        a.period,
        a.qualified,
        a.missed,
        a.desired_behavior_prior_qualified_was_missed, 
        coalesce(b.missed,0) as prior_qualified_was_missed
from data_1 a
LEFT JOIN data b on concat(b.customer,b.period) = a.period_qualified_customer 
order by customer;
```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer.